# zero padding fft

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I have an image of size 786*786 and I would like to zero pad it to make it 1024*1024 so I that I can use my radix 2 algorithm. In the input side I would basically add zeros at the end so that the length would be 1024*1024 and my fft would produce a 1024*1024 output, my question is how do I retrieve the correct 786*786 output?

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the FFT is still *correct*, even though you zero padded the input. The difference is that the output has been interpolated in the frequency domain, so you have more *apparent* resolution (although of course no more information has been magically gained - you are just seeing additional points due to the interpolation). If you do an inverse FFT you will get back to your original zero padded input.

Comment: Thank you the results of inverse fft match with the original sample!!